# Not able to select a list item in an unordered list using selenium python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
I need to select a list item in an unordered list using selenium python. 

HTML:
<div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
    <ul style="max-height: 400px;">
        <li class="ms-select-all">      
            <label><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectAlls_osVer">
                [Select all]
            </label>    
        </li>

        <li class="" style="false">     
            <label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItems_osVer" value="KK">
                <span style="">
                    KK 
                </span>
            </label>        
        </li>

        <li class="" style="false">
            <label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItems_osVer" value="KK_MR1">
                <span style="">
                    KK_MR1 
                </span>
            </label>        
        </li>

        <li class="" style="false">
            <label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItems_osVer" value="KK_MR2">
                <span style="">
                    KK_MR2 
                </span>
            </label>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



Tried code:
```

unordered_list is a variable containing the unordered list.
os_version contains some text. say os_version = "KK"

Once you start traversing through the list items in an unordered list we need to select the matched item checkbox.

```
unordered_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fixedHeadSearch']/td[7]/div/div/ul") 

list_items = unordered_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

for list_item in list_items:
    print(list_item.text)     
if list_item.text == os_version:
    list_item.click()   



Expected:if text matches with list item perform click on it.
Actual:Not able to click on required list item.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `Xpath` option to click on input checkbox whose label text is `KK`

```
os_version = "KK"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ms-drop bottom']//ul//li[.//span[normalize-space(text())='"+ os_version + "']]//input").click()
```

---

Or You can induce `WebDriverWait`  and `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
os_version = "KK"
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ms-drop bottom']//ul//li[.//span[normalize-space(text())='"+ os_version + "']]//input"))).click()
```

You need to import followings to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fixedHeadSearch']//ul/li[text()=" + os_version + "]").click()
```