# Unable to select checkboxes with a list item in a dropdown list due to Timeoutexception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to perform automation on a web page using chrome web driver in selenium python.

In one case i have a drop down list with 80 list items ,each list item preceeding with an input check box. I need to click on 2 check boxes from a given list matching with list item text.

Unable to select check boxes with a list item in a drop down list due to TimeoutException.

I am getting Timeout exception while trying to click on list item with check boxes in a drop down.
Note:

1.Also observed a loading indicator appears once a drop down list is clicked using moveToElement.

2.Dropdown list has around 80 list items and it has scroll bar.
3.This dropdown list is present immediate to another drop down listed in below link.

I followed :[Not able to select a list item in an unordered list using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507901/not-able-to-select-a-list-item-in-an-unordered-list-using-selenium-python)

Started using webdriver wait with expected Conditions concept.

```
   HTML :
   HTML code:
   =========
   <div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
       <ul style="max-height: 400px;">
           <li class="ms-select-all">      
               <label><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectAlls_osVer">
                   [Select all]
               </label>    
           </li>

           <li class="" style="false">     
               <label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItems_osVer" value="KK">
                   <span>
                     apq40 
                   </span>
               </label>        
           </li>

           <li class="" style="false">
               <label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItems_osVer" value="KK_MR1">
                   <span>
                     sdm845  
                   </span>
               </label>        
           </li>

           <li class="" style="false">
               <label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItems_osVer" value="KK_MR2">
                   <span>
                     msm8996 
                   </span>
               </label>        
           </li>
       <li class="" style="false">
               <label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItems_osVer" value="KK_MR2">
                   <span>
                     msm8996e 
                   </span>
               </label>        
           </li>
            .....
            ..... so on (approximately 80 elements are there)
       </ul>
   </div>
```

****Tried with below code but getting Time out exception:****

Language:Python
Driver:Selenium
Browser:chrome
webdriver:Chromewebdriver

I am getting Timeout exception while trying to click on listitem with check boxes in a drop down list .

```
chipset = [ 'sdm845', 'msm8996e' ]

for i in range(len(chipset)):
    chipset_name = "{}".format(chipset[i])

    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable
    ((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ms-drop bottom']//ul//li[.//span
[normalize-space(text())='"+ chipset_name + "']]//input"))).click()
```

Note:
1.Also observed a loading indicator appears once a drop down list is clicked using moveToElement.

2.Drop down list has around 80 list items and it has scroll bar.
This drop down list is present immediately to another drop down.

3. My element is visible and it is 2nd & 4th list items to be selected in a drop down and it is visible. Though Time Out Exception occurs.
   Is it due to loading icon appears ?
4. Also i would like to know how to go ahead if my desired list item to be selected is invisible and it appears at the end of the list and to make it visible i need to perform scroll down the list.

Expected:Need to perform click operation on desired list item input check boxes matching with the each string in a given list.

Actual: Time out Exception Appears while trying to find a list item in a dropdown containing a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you wait till 20 second , for the elements in drop down to be loaded, but maybe you have issues with scroll in Selenium that cannot find all elements (all options), the trick here is to wait for only the first option in combo box, then you should know that drop down is opened and you can choose element,

Comment: I tried keeping wait for 20 seconds. But still i am getting TimeoutException after performing click on another dropdown which  is adjacent to first dropdown.Actually i observed here both having similar xpath.

Comment: tried keeping wait for 20 seconds. But still i am getting TimeoutException after performing click on another dropdown which  is adjacent to first dropdown.Actually i observed here both having similar xpath.like given below. with multiple list items.<td>
 <div class="ms-parent" style="width:100px;">
  <div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
   <ul style="max-height: 400px;">
    <li class="ms-select-all">  
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectAlls_osVer">
     [Select all]
    </label> 
   </li>
                 </div>
        </div>
</td>How to proceed?

Comment: The best practice for my opinion is to wait at least 60 second for an element , second try to use maybe cssSelector for example: input[data-name=something] , check you Selenium selectors with chrome development tool

Comment: After waiting for 60 secs, i got selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: whichis due to other element whose <divid="uiLockID".obscures it.I fixed the same using WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibility_of_element_located(By.ID,("uiLockID")));Thanks for the support.